# Run script in Kettle from records in table

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I have a table where multiple SQL scripts. I would like to make an ETL that runs these scripts on another bank line by line. We built a SQL editor that is used by multiple users, what we need to do now is that they run at a certain time of day by ETL.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Table Input` step in a transformation to read this table with these scripts. You can then hop the `Table Input` step to an `Execute Row SQL Script` step to execute the SQL scripts from the "script" column row-by-row.